# Output of Apart as a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation, coefficients

I have a rational function of one variable that I know will always have a simple partial fraction decomposition of the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\alpha_n}{z- \beta_n},$$

but I do not know the values of the $\{\alpha_n\}$ or the $\{\beta_n\}$ in advance of doing the partial fraction decomposition, and $N$ can take larger values (say up to 20 or 30). I would like to write a program that automatically puts the $\{\alpha_n\}$ in one list and the $\{\beta_n\}$ in another. Is there a way to do this using the `Apart[]` output?

Comment: It would be useful to have a concrete example, in Mathematica input format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create test case

```
m = 3;

t = Total[Array[a, m]/(z - Array[b, m])] // Together;
```

Test function

```
f = Numerator[t]/Expand[Denominator[t]]

(* (z^2 a[1] + z^2 a[2] + z^2 a[3] - z a[2] b[1] - z a[3] b[1] - z a[1] b[2] - 
   z a[3] b[2] + a[3] b[1] b[2] - z a[1] b[3] - z a[2] b[3] + a[2] b[1] b[3] +
    a[1] b[2] b[3])/(z^3 - z^2 b[1] - z^2 b[2] + z b[1] b[2] - z^2 b[3] + 
   z b[1] b[3] + z b[2] b[3] - b[1] b[2] b[3]) *)
```

Function to extract terms

```
pf[func_, var_Symbol] := Module[
  {af = List @@ Apart[func, var]},
  {Numerator /@ af, var - (Denominator /@ af)}]
```

Check

```
pf[f, z]

(* {{a[1], a[2], a[3]}, {b[1], b[2], b[3]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If $f=P/Q$, with $P$ and $Q$ relatively prime polynomials, then the $\beta_k$ are the roots of $Q$ and $\alpha_k = P(\beta_k)/Q'(\beta_k)$. So we can skip `Apart` and avoid the trouble of rewriting it.

```
getPFDparameters[rat0_, z_] := Module[{rat, numfn, denfn, beta, alpha},
  rat = Together[rat0];
  numfn = Evaluate[Numerator@rat /. z -> #] &;
  denfn = Evaluate[Denominator@rat /. z -> #] &;
  beta = SolveValues[denfn[z] == 0, z];
  alpha = numfn[beta]/denfn'[beta];
  {alpha, beta}
  ];
```

Examples:

```
rat = 2/(z + 1) + -5/(z - 1) + 7/(z - 2) + 4/(z - 3) // Together // 
  Simplify
getPFDparameters[rat, z]
```

> ```
> (*
> (-13 + 6 z - 21 z^2 + 8 z^3)/(-6 + 5 z + 5 z^2 - 5 z^3 + z^4)
> {{2, -5, 7, 4}, {-1, 1, 2, 3}}
> *)
> ```

```
(* @BobHanlon's example *)
deg = 6;
rat = Total[Array[a, deg]/(z - Array[b, deg])] // Together;
getPFDparameters[rat, z] // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*
> {{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]},
>  {b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6]}}
> *)
> ```

```
deg = 6;
SeedRandom[0];
rat = FromDigits[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, deg], z]/
   FromDigits[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, deg + 1], z];
getPFDparameters[rat, z] // 
 TableForm[#, TableDirections -> Row, 
   TableHeadings -> {{"alpha", "beta"}, None}] &
```

> [image]