# Normalizing the output of Apart

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation, coefficients

My question is closely related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/185746/87546) but the accepted answer does not meet my needs.

I have a rational function $f(x)$ in one variable which admits a partial fraction decomposition of the form
$$\sum_k\frac{A_k}{(x-\alpha_k)^{d_k}}$$
unknown in advance. I would like to produce from $f(x)$ the list of triples $\left\{ (A_k,\alpha_k,d_k)\right\}$ or three lists $\left\{A_k\right\}$, $\left\{\alpha_k\right\}$, $\left\{d_k\right\}$. Can this be done, say, using the function **Apart**?

More exactly, my problem with the [existing answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185749/87546) is that it *only* works in pathological examples where the polynomials appearing in the denominator after the application of **Apart** are monic. For example, it already fails to produce $\left\{\left\{3/2\right\},\left\{1/2\right\}\right\}$ for $f(x)=3/(2x-1)$. Is there a simple way to correct this?

**Update**: Consider a test function $f(x)=\frac{3}{(2x-1)(4x-3)^2}$ which has a decomposition $$f(x)=\frac{3}{2\left(x-\frac12\right)}+\frac{3}{8\left(x-\frac34\right)^2}-\frac{3}{2\left(x-\frac34\right)}.$$
In this case the code should produce three lists $$A=\left\{\tfrac32,\tfrac38,-\tfrac32\right\},\qquad \alpha=\left\{\tfrac12,\tfrac34,\tfrac34\right\},\qquad d=\left\{1,2,1\right\}.$$
Finally I have managed to produce something that works:

```
f[k_] := 3/((2*k - 1)*(4*k - 3)^2); 
numer := Numerator[List @@ Apart[f[k], k]]; 
denom := Denominator[List @@ Apart[f[k], k]]; 
poles := First /@ (k /. Solve[#1 == 0, {k}] & ) /@ denom; 
expos := Exponent[denom, k]; 
coefs := Limit[denom/k^expos, k -> Infinity]; 
{numer/coefs, poles, expos}
```

with the expected result

[image]

This is okay for my purposes but maybe there is a nicer solution that would not involve taking the limits? (in principle all information is already contained in the result of application of **List@@Apart**)

Comment: Please provide what you tried as code. We can't answer a code question without seen the code you used. You may also be interested in [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202112)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the variable `k` as needed:

```
pfd = Apart[3/((2*k - 1)*(4*k - 3)^2), k];
pfdData = Replace[List @@ pfd,
   a_.*Power[c_. k + b_., d_] :> {a*c^d, -b/c, -d},
   1]
desiredLists = Transpose@pfdData
(*
{{3/2, 1/2, 1}, {3/8, 3/4, 2}, {-(3/2), 3/4, 1}}
{{3/2, 3/8, -(3/2)}, {1/2, 3/4, 3/4}, {1, 2, 1}}
*)
```

Alternative, using the undocumented function `` Integrate`ComplexApart[] ``, which does the decomposition in the form desired by the OP:

```
pfd = Integrate`ComplexApart[3/((2*k - 1)*(4*k - 3)^2), k];
pfdData = 
 Replace[List @@ pfd, a_.*Power[k + b_., d_] :> {a, -b, -d}, 1]
desiredLists = Transpose@pfdData
(*
{{3/8, 3/4, 2}, {-(3/2), 3/4, 1}, {3/2, 1/2, 1}}
{{3/8, -(3/2), 3/2}, {3/4, 3/4, 1/2}, {2, 1, 1}}
*)
```

Comment: Alternative to the alternative: ``Integrate`ComplexApart[3/((2*k - 1)*(4*k - 3)^2), k] /. {Plus | Times | Power -> List, k -> Nothing} // Map@Flatten // Transpose`` (assumes the orderless arguments of `Plus` and `Times` always occur in the right order).

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

To reuse the previous answer

```
k = 4;

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {A, a, d};

(f[x_] = 
   Total[Array[A, k]/(x - Array[a, k])^Array[d, k]]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
dList = Cases[f[x], Power[b_, -exp_] :> exp, Infinity]
```

[image]

```
f2[x_] = f[x] /. Power[b_, -exp_] :> Power[b, -1]
```

[image]

```
pf[func_, var_Symbol] := 
 Module[{af = List @@ Apart[func, var]}, {Numerator /@ af, 
   var - (Denominator /@ af)}]

{Alist, aList} = pf[f2[x] // Together, x]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
Clear["Global`*"]

kmax = 4;

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {a, b, c, d};

(f[x_] = Sum[b[k]/(c[k]*x - a[k])^d[k], {k, 1, kmax}]) //
  TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
({αList, Alist, dList} = 
 Transpose@Cases[List @@ f[x], b_.*(c_.*x - a_)^d_ :> {a/c, b/c^(-d), -d}, 1]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
f[x] == Total[Alist/(x - αList)^dList] // 
 Simplify[#, Element[Array[d, kmax], PositiveIntegers]] &

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However my main problem with the previous code is not the inclusion of higher order poles but the fact that the coefficients of the leading powers of $x$ in the denominators are in general different from $1$. If I understand correctly, this is not corrected in the new code (e.g. for $f(x)=3/(2x-1)$ **Denominator/@Apart[3/(2x-1)]** gives $2x-1$ and not $x-1/2$ as I would like).

Comment: Edit your question to show your actual problem. Your example does not match the form that you said you were working with.

Comment: It does (I never said $A_k$ or $\alpha_k$ are integers) but I will try to make it more clear.